# How to determine the position of an error in the input document with Poco Json Parser?

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries

I am using the Poco C++ Json Parser. If the input document contains a Json syntax error, the parser throws an exception of type Poco::JSON::JSONException. My problem is that this exception type does not hold any information on the location of the error in the input document.

However the users need some hint on where the problem is so they can fix it. Is there any way I can get it?

EDIT:

For example, if the JSON input looks like this:

```
{
  "objects": [
  {
    "timestamp: "2019-09-13T01:30:00.000Z",
    ...
```

The displayText() of the JSONException is:

error: 4: expected ':' after property name

No mention of a line number oder column (in the input document) whatsoever.

I am using Poco 1.9.0.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because you are expected to provide a [mcve] .  And you had the wrong tag.  (poco-libraries instead of poco). I fixed the latter for you.

Comment: @selbie: Thanks for fixing the tag. Concerning the code example: I usually understand well the necessity of a code example but in this case, the question is independent from any concrete program code. Does a code example make sense then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about POCO, but a glance at the code suggests that the exception has a "message" field that contains the line number in which the json error occurred at - along with other useful information about the parse error.

From [ParserImpl.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/JSON/src/ParserImpl.cpp#L223):

```
    case JSON_ERROR:
    {
        const char* pErr = json_get_error(_pJSON);
        std::string err(pErr ? pErr : "JSON parser error.");
        throw JSONException(err);
    }
```

Where that error string originates from this macro in [pdjson.c](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/JSON/src/pdjson.c#L15):

```
#define json_error(json, format, ...)                             \
    if (!(json->flags & JSON_FLAG_ERROR)) {                       \
        json->flags |= JSON_FLAG_ERROR;                           \ 
        snprintf(json->errmsg, sizeof(json->errmsg),              \
                 "error: %lu: " format,                           \
                 (unsigned long) json->lineno,    <<=== THERE'S YOUR LINE NUMBER
                 __VA_ARGS__);                                    \
    }
```

So the exception has everything the parser is capable of suggesting back to the user.  Catch the JSONExcepton and literally print exception.message() back to the user.  But that might require a modification if you want to support non-English.  In any case, it doesn't look like it would be difficult to include the `json->lineno` formally into the JSONException class with a few modifications to the code.  But not all errors have a line number - some are "unexpected end of file".

Comment: Thanks for this valuable hint. The line no simply does not show up as I have added to the question. But I will research from here.

Comment: Now I get it. "error: 4" does not mean error with code 4 but error in line 4. Strange error text however. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: However as far as I can see, there is no way to access the struct json_stream::lineno from outside.

Comment: What I was trying to get at it with my answer is that you will need to modify the source code for POCO to stuff more error information into data structures and exceptions thrown.  But just parsing for "error: %d" might be all you really need to do.